# Ansible Module "lineinfile" replace multiple lines in several files

Tags: apache, ssl, ansible

our SSL certificate runs out in a couple of days. So I thought Ansible can put the new certs on the server und change the apache2 sites.

Serveral sites are running on this server.

I want to replace the following lines:

> - SSLCertificateChainFile
> - SSLCertificateKeyFile
> - SSLCertificateFile

I use this command to get a list of all sites in /etc/apache2 where the pattern "SSLCertificate" exists.

```
- name: Apache 2.2 list sites files and store it in register
  command: grep -lR --exclude default-ssl "SSLCertificate" /etc/apache2/
  register: apache22_sites
```

This is what I use, when only one file has to be changed:

```
- name: apache2.2.* | configure certs
  lineinfile: dest=/path/to/...  regexp={{ item.regexp }} line={{ item.line}} backrefs=yes
  with_items:
        - { regexp: "SSLCertificateChainFile", line: "    SSLCertificateChainFile = ..." }
        - { regexp: "SSLCertificateKeyFile ", line: "    SSLCertificateKeyFile = ..." }
        - { regexp: "SSLCertificateFile", line: "    SSLCertificateFile = ..."
  notify: reload apache2
```

How can i tell ansible to use this code with multiple files listed in variable "apache22_sites" **and** multiples lines?

I found a good hint [here](https://u.osu.edu/hasnan.1/2013/12/11/ansible-replace-in-line-of-code-in-multiple-files-in-a-directory/), bad sadly only for one line.

I appreciate any tipps, tricks, hints :)

Greetings
Dennis

Comment: Using lineinfile like this isn't good practice- you should be using the template module.

Answer (score 2):

As [tedder42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/659298/tedder42) pointed out in the comments, and as is generally the case when people are using [`lineinfile`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html), you'd be much better off [templating](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html) these files instead.

However, if you want to solve the more general problem of how you loop through multiple lists of things then you should be using the [`with_nested` loop](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#nested-loops).

So in your case you would have something like:

```
- name: Apache 2.2 list sites files and store it in register
  command: grep -lR --exclude default-ssl "SSLCertificate" /etc/apache2/
  register: apache22_sites

- name: apache2.2.* | configure certs
  lineinfile: dest={{ item.0 }}  regexp={{ item.1.regexp }} line={{ item.1.line}} backrefs=yes
  with_nested:
        - apache22_sites
        - lines_to_replace
  notify: reload apache2
```

As long as you define your `lines_to_replace` somewhere like this:

```
lines_to_replace:
    - { regexp: "SSLCertificateChainFile", line: "    SSLCertificateChainFile = ..." }
    - { regexp: "SSLCertificateKeyFile ", line: "    SSLCertificateKeyFile = ..." }
    - { regexp: "SSLCertificateFile", line: "    SSLCertificateFile = ..."
```