# Replace several words in matching files using Ansible

Tags: loops, text, replace, ansible

The project is to update wildcard certificate paths on many servers, each having a differently-named Vhost-*.conf file.

I would like to search for files that match `V*.conf`, then grep through them and replace the values for `crt`, `key` & `ca` as indicated below.

The closest answer I've found is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37846995/6837022) but I couldn't get it to run as-is. And I think the `replace` module is better suited than lineinfile since I'd rather not re-write the whole line, and would like to replace any number of occurrences in the file.

After some changes this is the closest I've come, but I haven't figured out why my syntax is off:

```
---
- hosts: myhost5
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: grab conf file names
    shell: ls /etc/httpd/conf.d/V*.conf
    register: vhost_files
  - name: replace text
    replace:
      dest: '{{ item.0 }}'
      regexp: '{{ item.1.regexp }}'
      line: '{{ item.1.line}}'
      backrefs: yes
      backup: yes
    with_nested:
      - "{{vhost_files}}"
      - "{{text_to_replace}}"
  vars:
    text_to_replace:
      - { "regexp: 'mywildcard2014.crt', line: 'mywildcard.2016.crt'" }
      - { "regexp: 'mywildcard2048_2014.key', line: 'mywildcard.2016.key'" }
      - { "regexp: 'gd_bundle2014.crt', line: 'mywildcard.2016.ca-bundle'" }

  handlers:
  - name: restart apache
    service: name=httpd state=restarted
```

The response I get is:

```
the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a 
variable that is undefined. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'regexp'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to remove unnecessary double quotes here:

```
- { regexp: 'mywildcard2014.crt', line: 'mywildcard.2016.crt' }
```

But there are number of other tiny bugs in your code.
Also keep in mind that using shell commands instead of modules is not an Ansible way.
Consider using `find` module instead of `shell: ls`.

```
---
- hosts: myhost5
  become: yes
  vars:
    text_to_replace:
      - { regexp: 'mywildcard2014.crt', line: 'mywildcard.2016.crt' }
      - { regexp: 'mywildcard2048_2014.key', line: 'mywildcard.2016.key' }
      - { regexp: 'gd_bundle2014.crt', line: 'mywildcard.2016.ca-bundle' }
  tasks:
  - name: grab conf file names
    find:
      pattern: V*.conf
      path: /etc/httpd/conf.d/
    register: vhost_files
  - name: replace text
    replace:
      dest: '{{ item.0.path }}'
      regexp: '{{ item.1.regexp }}'
      replace: '{{ item.1.line}}'
      backup: yes
    with_nested:
      - "{{vhost_files.files}}"
      - "{{text_to_replace}}"
    notify: restart apache

  handlers:
  - name: restart apache
    service: name=httpd state=restarted
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help cleaning up that filthy code! Thanks Konstantin for your help!

Comment: @Konstantin, I used above code.

- conf_replace: 
      - { regexp: 'PROPERTIES=info', line: '#PROPERTIES=info' }
      - { regexp: 'BINARY=default', line: '#BINARY=default' }
tasks:
  -
      name: Replace details      
      replace:
        dest: '/usr/share/properties'
        regexp: "{{ item.0.regexp }}"
        replace: "{{ item.0.line }}"
        backup: yes
      with_nested:
        - "{{ conf_replace }}"